# Google+ Sign-In - stop requesting people you're connected with

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-plus

Is there a way to make the Google+ Sign-In not request the user's "list of people you're connected to on Google+"?

My goal is to use the G+ sign in for authentication purposes today, and in the future also use it for social sharing functionality.  As the owner/operator of the service requesting sign in I don't care who is in a user's circles.

Is it possible to remove the request for all of the people a user is connected with?  Am I missing something with this?  For example if I didn't request all of a user's connected people would the user no longer be able to share to them?

I'm aware of the Google OpenId sign in functionality, but it doesn't provide the functionality I'd like for the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you use the Google+ sign-in button, the scope plus.login is added.  As such, it will request the "know who you are on Google+" and "List of people you are connected with". A few notes on this:

1. The user has control over which people they share with you so if they don't want to share this information, it's within their control.
2. If you're interested in the information in the future - using the existing connections people have is a great way to make your site better - the access will be available to you.

If you still feel you should be able to just request the user's profile, please add a star/feature request to the issue tracker here:

https://developers.google.com/+/

The more information regarding why you want to do this and the clearer your request explanation, the better!